# How to solve the recurrence relation for this Multiplication algorithm

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, multiplication, recurrence

How to I establish a big-O upper bound for the number of times the function calls itself, as a function of b for the following:

```
  function multiply(a,b)
     if b = 0 then return 0
     else if b is even then
       t := multiply(a, b/2);
       return t+t;
     else if b is odd then
       t := multiply(a, b-1);
       return a+t;
```

this is a function to multiply two integer numbers. I'm confused on how to handle the if else conditions for the recurrence relation. I was thinking that the answer is T(n) = T(n/2) + T(n-1). Is that correct?

Comment: b gets halved every 1 (if b is even) or 2 (odd) iterations. Therefore, there can be at most 2 * log(b) executions of this function. Thus, log(b) is the required upper bound.

Comment: Also note that this function is extremely similar to [Exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

Answer (score 2):

```
 function multiply(a,b)
     if b = 0 then return 0
     else if b is even then
       t := multiply(a, b/2);
       return t+t;
     else if b is odd then
       t := multiply(a, b-1);
       return a+t;
```

Therefore:

```
F(0) = 0
If Even: F(N) = F(N/2) + 1 
If Odd-Even: F(N) = F(N-1) + 1 = F((N-1)/2) + 2 <-next number is definitely even
```

Solving the odd-even-odd-even case(the worst scenario):

```
F(N) = F((N-1)/2) + 2 = O(LogN)
```

Another way to think of the problems is that we know the odd-even-odd-even case has at most twice the depth of even-even-even-even case. The even only case has `LogN` depth, thus odd-even-odd-even case has at most `2*LogN` depth.

Comment: " F((N-1)/2) + 2 <-next number is definitely even " this part is not true from what you said since if b = 6, then b/2 = 3 is odd

Comment: @Ana 6 is not a odd number, when analyzing the worse case in terms of N we know odd-even-odd-even sequence is worse, thus solving it make sense

Comment: if we take 7, then we get 6, then 3, then 2, then 1. so It's more like and nlogn time

Comment: @Ana It is logN time (you are halving it once every 2 func call, Assuming there are logN call when number is always even, we then know there are 2logN depth for odd-even-odd-even). NlogN doesn't make sense

Comment: @Ana It is `logN` behavior, because it takes at most _two_ steps to reach another even number, which would then result in the input being halved again.

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate the following two points:

- Calling `multiply` with an *odd* input will trigger a call to the same input minus one, which is an even number.  This will take one additional call to reach an even number.
- Calling `multiply` with an even input will trigger another call with the input halved.  The resulting number will either be even, or odd, q.v. the above point.

In the worst case scenario, starting with an even input, it would take *two* calls to halve the input being passed to `multiply`.  This behavior is consistent with `2*O(lgN)` running time (where `lg` is the log base 2).  This is the same as just `O(lgN)`.

Comment: but if b = 7, it will call multiply(a,6) then call multiply(a,3)  then call multiply(a,2). So calling an even function does not necessarily mean "calling with an even input will again trigger a call with an even input" from your second statement

Comment: @Ana You're right, and I changed my answer, which however comes to the same conclusion.